# Classifier for DBSCAN

Tags: machine-learning, classification, anomaly-detection, dbscan

I have written a code that uses DBSCAN and tries to find the most appropriate eps for my dataset, trying to include most of the data inside a cluster.

The problem is that DBSCAN is not a classifier and I want to make use of the results that I have gotten from the code to run it upon other dataset to check for anomalies.